# Redirect when Javascript placed in another domain

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript redirect like this:

```
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

is it possible for me to create that javascript only work 
when its placed in a domain other than stackoverflow? but when placed on stackoverflow, then the javascript will not work.

Comment: check if the substring exists in your url before redirecting?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

Check if the current domain is `stackoverflow`

**Step 2**

Redirect if the current domain is not.

**Oversimplified example**

```
if (!/stackoverflow\.com/ig.test(window.location.href))
    window.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com';
```